# Как правильно сделать псевдо-элемент треугольник в меню?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Сайт делается под вордпресс, использую сетку бутстрап и адаптивную верстку вордпресса.
Хочу вставить псевдо-элемент треугольник в меню, но по какой-то причине он встает не туда куда надо, хочу сделать что-то типа такого.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот часть кода который не могу сделать

```
введите сюда https://codepen.io/Xva1er/pen/GRzVKmm
```

Comment: Вот ссылка на кусок кода https://codepen.io/Xva1er/pen/GRzVKmm

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8vLwpfo7/

Comment: https://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/

Comment: Касаемо псевдо-элементов я не устану повторять, что они не предназначены для стилизации элементов, ни идеологически, ни семантически. Однажды какой-то идиот начал делать так и все зачем-то стали за ним повторять. Единственным правильным решением здесь является сделать этот элемент в SVG. Остается только аккуратно позиционировать его по вертикали относительно высоты шрифта. Здесь можно сделать разными способами: vertical-align в модуле инлайн, align-items в модуле flex, ну или на худой конец background-position.

Comment: @NNL993 Вы свое решение видели при включенном масштабировании в браузере? Все разваливается на два куска. Наглядный пример, как не надо делать псевдо-элементами.